# Confusion about lua corountine's resume and yield function

Tags: lua, coroutine

I am learning lua by this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rjY2UbEqWII), it has this piece of code:

```
co = coroutine.create(function()
    for i=1,5 do
      print(coroutine.yield(i))
    end
  end)

print(coroutine.resume(co,1,2))
print(coroutine.resume(co,3,4))
print(coroutine.resume(co,5,6))
print(coroutine.resume(co,7,8))
print(coroutine.resume(co,9,10))
print(coroutine.resume(co,11,12))
```

The output is like this:

```
true    1
3   4
true    2
5   6
true    3
7   8
true    4
9   10
true    5
11  12
true
```

But I don't understand how yield and resume passes parameters to each other and why yield doesn't output the first 1,2 that resume passes to it, could someone please explain? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normal Lua functions have one entry (where arguments get passed in) and one exit (where return values are passed out):

```
local function f( a, b )
  print( "arguments", a, b )
  return "I'm", "done"
end

print( "f returned", f( 1, 2 ) )
--> arguments       1       2
--> f returned      I'm     done
```

The arguments are bound to the parameter names (local variables) by putting them inside the parentheses, the return values listed as part of the `return` statement can be retrieved by putting the function call expression in the right-hand side of an assignment statement, or inside of a larger expression (e.g. another function call).

There are alternative ways to call a function. E.g. `pcall()` calls a function and catches any runtime errors that may be raised inside. Arguments are passed in by putting them as arguments into the `pcall()` function call (right after the function itself). `pcall()` also prepends an additional return value that indicates whether the function exited normally or via an error. The inside of the called function is unchanged.

```
print( "f returned", pcall( f, 1, 2 ) )
--> arguments       1       2
--> f returned      true    I'm     done
```

You can call the main function of a coroutine by using `coroutine.resume()` instead of `pcall()`. The way the arguments are passed, and the extra return value stays the same:

```
local th = coroutine.create( f )
print( "f returns", coroutine.resume( th, 1, 2 ) )
--> arguments       1       2
--> f returns       true    I'm     done
```

But with coroutines you get another way to (temporarily) exit the function: `coroutine.yield()`. You can pass values out via `coroutine.yield()` by putting them as arguments into the `yield()` function call. Those values can be retrieved outside as return values of the `coroutine.resume()` call instead of the normal return values.

However, you can re-enter the yielded coroutine by again calling `coroutine.resume()`. The coroutine continues where it left off, and the extra values passed to `coroutine.resume()` are available as return values of the `yield()` function call that suspended the coroutine before.

```
local function g( a, b )
  print( "arguments", a, b )
  local c, d = coroutine.yield( "a" )
  print( "yield returned", c, d )
  return "I'm", "done"
end

local th = coroutine.create( g )
print( "g yielded", coroutine.resume( th, 1, 2 ) )
print( "g returned", coroutine.resume( th, 3, 4 ) )
--> arguments       1       2
--> g yielded       true    a
--> yield returned  3       4
--> g returned      true    I'm     done
```

Note that the yield need not be directly in the main function of the coroutine, it can be in a nested function call. The execution jumps back to the `coroutine.resume()` that (re-)started the coroutine in the first place.

Now to your question why the `1, 2` from the first `resume()` doesn't appear in your output: Your coroutine main function doesn't list any parameters and so ignores all arguments that are passed to it (on first function entry). On a similar note, since your main function doesn't return any return values, the last `resume()` doesn't return any extra return values besides the `true` that indicates successful execution as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
co = coroutine.create(function()
    for i=1,5 do
      print(coroutine.yield(i))
    end
  end)
```

We start the coroutine the first time using:

```
print(coroutine.resume(co,1,2))
```

it will run until the first yield. our first resume call will return true and the parameters of yield (here i = 1) which explains the first output line.

our coroutine is now suspended. once we call resume a second time:

```
print(coroutine.resume(co,3,4))
```

your first yield finally returns and the parameters of your current resume (3,4) will be printed. the for loops second iteration begins, coroutine.yield(2) is called, supending the coroutine which again will make your last resume return true, 2 and so on

So actually in your example coroutine.resume(co) would be sufficient for the first call as any further arguments are lost anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that the yield function actually passes its parameter as well as true to the resume function before it returns?

Comment: no true is returned if there was no error in resume.

Answer (score 1):

The reason we see this behavior is subtle, but it has to do with a mismatch of "entering" and "exiting" `yield` statements. It also has to do with the order in which `print` and `yield` are called within your anonymous function.

Let's imagine a graph of the execution of `print(coroutine.yield(i))` vs. iteration.

On the first iteration, we have `coroutine.resume` pass `1` and `2` to the coroutine. This is the origin point, so we **are not** picking up from **a former** `yield`, but rather the original call of the anonymous function itself. The `yield` is called inside the print, returning `i=1` but leaving `print` uncalled. The function exits.

What follows is the suspension of the function for a time before we see resumption by the next `coroutine.resume`.This `resume` passes `3` and `4`. The function **picks up at the last** `yield`. Remember that the `print` function was left uncalled as the 1st `yield` was called first and exited the program? Well, execution returns inside the `print`, and so `print` now gets called, but this time returning `3` and `4` as these were the latest values to be transferred over. The function repeats again, calling `yield` before `print`, returning `i=2`.

If we go down the iterations we will more definitely the pattern underlying why we didn't see the `1` and `2`. Our first iteration was an "exiting" yield unpaired with a corresponding "entering yield." This corresponds to the 1st time execution of the coroutine `co`.

We might expect the last `yield` to also go unpaired, but the difference is that we'll have an "entering" `yield` which is unpaired as opposed to an "exiting" `yield` which is unpaired. This is because the loop would have already finished. This explains why we see `11  12` followed by `true` followed with no "exiting" `yield` return.

This sort of situation is independent of the parity (even/oddness) of the for loop inside. What only matters are the `resume` and `yield` pairs and the manner in which they are handled. You have to appreciate that `yield` won't return a value within the function on the first call of `resume` which is being used to call the function inside the coroutine in the first place.